# Select each dynamic inner div in event bubbling

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, event-bubbling

I have a static HTML container div like this:

```
<div id="dvExchangeNames">
</div>
```

on `document.ready()` event, I get some strings using Ajax call and append each of string as `div` content inside the container `dvExchangeNames`. The new HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="dvExchangeNames">

  <div class='drop'> Foo </div>
  <div class='drop'> Bar </div>

</div>
```

I need to bind `ondrop` event on the div with **drop** class. So I do it like this using event bubbling:

```
$("#dvExchangeNames").on("dropstart", ".drop", function () {

    $(this).addClass("active");

}).on("drop", function (ev, dd) {

    $(this).toggleClass("dropped");

}).on("dropend", function () {

    $(this).removeClass("active");
});
```

The problem is that it adds, toggles and removes the classes from `dvExchangeNames` but I want this to be done with the **child div which actually fired** the `dropstart` event.

As obviously, `$(this)` selects the parent div. I tried `$(e.target).addClass()` but it didn't work. I'm using **[THIS](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop/demo/selection)** jQuery plugin to get multi select functionality using drag-drop.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is `event delegation` again `.on` for `drop` and `dropend` obviously targets `#dvExchangeNames` as you mentioned. So make it `event delegation` for all the `events` as below:

```
$("#dvExchangeNames").on("dropstart", ".drop", function () {
    $(this).addClass("active");
}).on("drop",".drop", function (ev, dd) {
    //event delegation here
    $(this).toggleClass("dropped");
}).on("dropend",".drop", function () {
    //event delegation here too
    $(this).removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: @Guruprassad Rao: I tried adding the delegation event but it didn't work. Can you provide a code example?

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi I could have but am not able to create a demo since the plugin isn't available as a `CDN`.. I tried copying all the `js` but unfortunately not able to replicate the feature in fiddle..

Comment: @Guruprassad Rao: I switched to [this](https://jqueryui.com/selectable/) plugin and its working fine. Thank you for your help.